# How to uninstall VirtualRouter

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I have a problem uninstalling some software named VirtualRouter. I have tried to uninstall it through control panel. But it resulted in the following error. It always loads at the start up of the Windows7 loading, I mean it's listed as the start up application after its installation.

[image]

After the action, the software remains listed in the control panel and loads at every start up of my Windows7 and thus problem persists. How do I fix this?

Comment: Seems like it's missing some library... Did you try reinstalling it, then uninstalling it?

Comment: Is this the software you are trying to uninstall? http://virtualrouter.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, try to reinstall the program and uninstall it. The uninstallation problem may end with this.

If you can't uninstall it from Control Panel, there are many softwares to uninstall applications like IOBit Uninstaller, C Cleaner, Advanced Uninstaller. Try any of these and you may be able to uninstall.

If uninstallation is completely impossible then open your Task Manager -> Go to Start-Up -> Select this particular application from the list and Disable it. It won't load any more during the start-up.

If you want to remove this application from your disk, do this. Stop all the services of this particular application in Task Manger. Then go to the location where this application is installed and delete the folder of this application that was created during installation. Sometimes you may not be able to delete all files. In that case, restart your system and try to delete once again after stopping all services, if any is running.(This is not a good way to remove the application)

Comment: Also remember that some program installers will offer an `Uninstall` option when you already have the software installed. It's easy enough to check, just run the installer again.

Answer (score 4):

There is no absolute way to uninstall software, unless you used installation monitoring software to install it. This is a piece of software that records whatever is changed by the installation and can revert it.

If you haven't used a piece of software like that, you can try to to install alternative add/remove software, and try to uninstall it from there. But rarely this works.

Finally, the best you can do other than fromatting is to install a good registry cleaner, and clean the registry. If it's good it will find the loose stuff and fix it for you.

Comment: You could also manually check the installation logs of whatever "installer wizard" was used during its installation and try to remove all the listed files. It will totally depend on the kind of installer though.

Comment: Even if you used installation monitoring software, the program might have left trails during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still having a problem, I would recommend using Revo Uninstaller.  If you use it, be careful, as with any tool of this type, it can cause more problems if not used correctly.  I've had success using it in situations you describe.

Answer (score 0):

And if all attempts using third party software programs fails:

- Make a full disk (image) backup of your system
- Start RegEdit, remove everything in the registry related to VirtualRouter
- Remove everything on disk related to VirtualRouter

You may have to reboot and repeat steps 2 and 3 as long as deletions in them fail.

Answer (score 0):

Use [autoruns.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to locate and disable the autorun of this program regardless of how it autoruns itself  e.g.:

- autostart service
- All Programs > Startup folder
- Run registry section
- task scheduler

As for the uninstallation error, there is nothing much you can do about it. A repair install followed by uninstallation *might* help.